# How to count number of occurrences in a column

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

i want to count (see above example) for its number how many times appears in the column. i have tried different ways but it was a big failure.

is very important for me.

PLease, could you help me??

thanks a lot for your effort.

1.89
2.18
2.18 
2.18 
2.18 
1.60
1.22
1.67 
2.14 
1.59 
1.72
1.72
1.59 
1.59
1.67 
1.22 
1.47 
1.22
1.59 
1.47

Comment: Please indicate what have you tried so far. What are you trying to count? You have shown a series of numbers in your question, please show clearly how your data is organized.

Comment: Do you know what formulas are, and what function are, and how to use them?  Have you looked to see whether there are any functions whose name begins with `COUNT`?